# Irssi: How can I close the DCC Server?

Tags: irssi

The server is on the port 0 with the command:

```
/dcc server
```

I have no idea of its use, so I would like to close it. How can I close the DCC server?

**Clarification:**

If you look at the help "/help dcc", you will see that the close-command applies only to "SEND, GET and CHAT". There is no mention about closing the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/dcc close server <port>`

Answer (score 1):

Irssi has a built in help system:

```
/help dcc server
```

Yields:

```
 /DCC SERVER [<+|-scf> <port>]
 - Starts a DCC SERVER on the specified port. The remote can connect
   to this server and initiate chat, send and fserve requests. You can
   specify + or - using any combination of the flags 's' (Send),
   'c' (Chat), or 'f' (Fserver)
```

If you don't enter the /dcc server command, the server will not be started.
[More information on DCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Client-to-Client)

Comment: Irssi informed that the server started at the port 0.

Comment: Please, see the updated clarification.

Comment: I get `No help for dcc server` after running your command. It seems that Ubuntu does not have all manuals for irssi by default.